# Android Set Notification after 3 hours

Tags: android, time, notifications, alarm

i am making an reminder application. If a user clicks the alert button, the alarm should be set for next 3 hours and a notification should be shown in the status bar after 3 hours completion.

I guess i have to use Alarm Manager to do this , but i dont know how to add 3 hours to current system time and set notification for that time.

Comment: Explained here: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/ , just remove the calendar and set it for 3 hours yourself

Answer (score 2):

follow it

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) sContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 3*60*60*1000, sAlertSender);
```